# SSO with keyclock Spring boot and JWT

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak

**Background:**
Recently I was playing around with Oauth2 and Single Sign-on features. I have successfully implemented a POC with Spring-Boot, Keycloak. I can be found here: https://github.com/rivu007/sso-springboot-keyclock

This a REST service and I am using keycloak as OAuth2 server to secured protected endpoints. The setup works great with access token (clientId and secret)

**Complication**

I would love to extend the POC with JWT. Keyclock provides signed JWT as client authenticator. I have generated the keys and certificate (keystore.jks) and updated the application.yml file accordingly:

```
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:18080/auth
  realm: sso
  resource: product-app
  credentials:
    jwt:
      client-keystore-file: "src/main/resources/keystore.jks"
      client-keystore-type: "jks"
      client-keystore-password: "storepw"
      client-key-password: "keypw"
      client-key-alias: "product-app"
      token-expiration: 10
  confidential-port: 0
  use-resource-role-mappings: true
  ssl-required: none
```

And `SecurityConfiguration.java` looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /**
     * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate() {
        return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(http);

        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                // Allow anonymous access to "/" path
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/protected*").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll().and()
            // Custom filter for logging in users at "/login"
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // Custom filter for authenticating users using tokens
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // Disable resource caching
            .headers().cacheControl();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        //auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

This is throwing exception the following exception:

```
2018-03-06 23:35:54.766 ERROR 60780 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.k.a.rotation.AdapterRSATokenVerifier   : Didn't find publicKey for kid: w3Qn-XFRI_1uGaLs8_bJxo_hYmHSs1_-EilRV7y98G4
2018-03-06 23:35:54.778 ERROR 60780 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Failed to verify token
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see that key id `w3Qn-XFRI_1uGaLs8_bJxo_hYmHSs1_-EilRV7y98G4` in the Keycloak Admin UI, under your realm -> Keys tab?
  Is it `active`?  In order for your `java-keystore` provider to be considered active, it must have a higher priority than the default, `rsa-generated` provider.

Comment: @TomCawley Yes it is correct. 
I am wondering about the JWT token. At the moment my application is generating the JWT but I think it shouldn't be the case. Keycloak should generate it. Is there any keycloak java client to do this?